# How to generate same elements in multiple divs?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create onlick function in multiple divs by using shot codes in javascript but I end up creating multiple javascript codes with different ids and onclick function.

I tried for loop function but it didn't work as well.

```
function copy() { 
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
}
function copy2() { 
  document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
}
function copy3() { 
  document.getElementById("label3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect3").value;
}
function copy4() { 
  document.getElementById("label4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect4").value;
}
function copy5() { 
  document.getElementById("label5").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect5").value;
}
function copy6() { 
  document.getElementById("label6").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect6").value;
}
function copy7() {
  document.getElementById("label7").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect7").value;
}
function copy8() { 
  document.getElementById("label8").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect8").value;
}
function copy9() { 
  document.getElementById("label9").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect9").value;
}
function copy10() { 
  document.getElementById("label10").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect10").value;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the for loop you tried but stated it did not work as well?

Comment: how is this code invoked? Are you simply trying to insert a new `select` menu in what ever DIV you choose?

Comment: What is the structure of the HTML? Please add more detail to your question

Answer (score 0):

try this concept and adjust your code.

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById("label"+i).innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect"+i).innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySelect1">Up above the world so high</div>
<div id="mySelect2">like a diamond in the sky</div>

<div id="label1"></div>
<div id="label2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand this question but can you not just make one function with a parameter? And loop the function with a for-loop if necessary.

```
function copy(id) {
  id = id || ""; //empty string if id is undefined
  document.getElementById("label" + id).innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect" + id).value;
}

function copyClick() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    copy(i);
  }
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="copyClick">Copy!</button>
```

---

Or if you have multiple buttons the `copyClick` function is not necessary.

```
<button onclick="function(){ copy(0) }">Copy 0!</button>
<button onclick="function(){ copy(1) }">Copy 1!</button>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How it will work on multiple buttons? Actually, I have to generate a box by clicking on the button. If I use the above javascript codes it will work but if I have to reduce the code and make it function in all button, it doesn't work.